# jquery tmpl function inside IF statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I've got the following tmpl

```
{{if (${this.getFileLimit()})}}
<div class="files_wrapper">
    <div class="add-files">Click to add items</div>
</div>
{{/if}}
```

And the JS Code:

```
$('.addFiles').html($("#template").tmpl(data,{
  getFileLimit: function(){
    if (Object.size(data.items) == 10)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
  }
}))
```

So in general function ${this.getFileLimit()} works (it renders text on screen), but no luck to add it inside IF statement, always get errors.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Anyone have and idia how to use functions inside IF?

Comment: where is `getFileLimit` defined?

Comment: In the tmpl call: .tmpl(data,{
  getFileLimit: function(){
    if (Object.size(data.items) == 10)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be...

```
{{if this.getFileLimit()}}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TaWst/).

It's also worth mentioning that jQuery Template is a dead project. If this is a new project, you may be better off with something else.